# R Function- Attempt to make it faster and Alternatives

Tags: r, function, sapply

How can I make the below function faster, for larger datasets it takes too long to complete sapply?

Here is wwhat I am attempting in the below code:

- Extracting a number from a string of characters.
- Since the extracted number may be 1 or 2 digits long. Therefore,I have used a control structure.
- I am using indices with the function to run this function which make this operation too long.

Please suggest alternatives.

- **Dataset Columns**

[image]

```
c<-NULL
c$sub<-substr(rt404$secs.1.,6,7)
c$secs<-NA
c<-as.data.frame(c)
subfun<-function(i,data){
  if (nchar(as.character(data[i,8]))==7) c[i,2]<-substr(data[i,8],6,6)
  else c[i,2]<-substr(data[i,8],6,7)
}
c$seconds<-sapply(1:(length(c[,1])),subfun,data=rt502)
```

Comment: Please make this reproducible.  The input is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c$secs <- ifelse(nchar(as.character(rt502[,8]))==7,
                 substr(rt502[,8],6,6),
                 substr(rt502[,8],6,7))
```

Is this what you are looking for?